# Assertion Listener is not working in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I want to validate my response ok or bad using **Response Assertion**.
I have set the **Response Field to Test as Response Message**.I have set Patterns to test as **"ok"**.

Bue the problem is,it shows green signal in result tree Listener even if i receive bad response. I have attached the screen shot.How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your response contains OK somewhere.

If you want to validate it returns a 200 code, check :

- response code
- equals
- replace oK by 200

But also add a reponse assertion that check a text in you page, in this case replace OK by the text and check Text response / And substring.